# sort array of objects with more than one criteria

Tags: arrays, sorting

Lets say that I have an array of objects:

```
let updatedEvents = [
{
 "code": "3894",
 "date": "2020-06-01T20:00:00+0300",
 "timestamp": 1591030800
},
{
 "code": "1976",
 "date": "2020-06-01T20:00:00+0300",
 "timestamp": 1591030800
},
{
 "code": "0482",
 "date": "2020-06-01T20:00:00+0300",
 "timestamp": 1591030800
},
{
 "code": "0408",
 "date": "2020-06-01T20:00:00+0300",
 "timestamp": 1591030800
},
];
```

If I want to sort them by event date and if event date is the same in any event then sort them by code in ascending order then the following would be correct? :

```
const sortedEventsByDateUniqueCode = updatedEvents.sort((eventOne, eventTwo) => {
 if (eventOne.date === eventTwo.date) {
  return -1;
 }
 if (eventOne.code > eventTwo.code) return 1;
 if (eventOne.code < eventTwo.code) return -1;
});
```

Comment: Maybe have the last 2 if statements inside the first if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an `or` condition in `sort`:

```js
var updatedEvents = [{ "code": "3894", "date": "2020-06-01T20:00:00+0300", "timestamp": 1591030800},{ "code": "1976", "date": "2020-06-01T20:00:00+0300", "timestamp": 1591030800},{ "code": "0482", "date": "2020-06-01T20:00:00+0300", "timestamp": 1591030800},{ "code": "0408", "date": "2020-06-01T20:00:00+0300", "timestamp": 1591030800},{ "code": "0482", "date": "2020-06-02T20:00:00+0300", "timestamp": 1591030800},{ "code": "03", "date": "2020-06-02T20:00:00+0300", "timestamp": 1591030800}];

var result = updatedEvents.sort((a,b)=>{ 
  return (new Date(a.date)- new Date(b.date)) || (a.code - b.code)
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I want to use 1 and -1.

Answer (score 1):

No: in your case, you start with

```js
if (eventOne.date === eventTwo.date) {
  return -1;
}
```

which will always put `eventOne` before `eventTwo` if they have the same `date`. However, what you want is to only check the `code` if they have the same `date`; otherwise, sort by `date`.

It gets quite verbose, but you can go for:

```js
if (eventOne.date < eventTwo.date) {
  return -1;
}
if (eventOne.date > eventTwo.date) {
  return 1;
}
if (eventOne.code < eventTwo.code) {
  return -1;
}
if (eventOne.code > eventTwo.code) {
  return 1;
}
return 0;
```

As I said however, this is quite verbose; it would be nice if you could use a shorter version.

gorak has helpfully given [a short one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62128209/1406083):

```js
return (new Date(eventOne.date) - new Date(eventTwo.date)) || (eventOne.code - eventTwo.code);
```

This works because dates and strings can be subtracted from each other (if two event `codes` have different lengths, then it may not work) and will return `0` if they are equal. `0` is falsey, so when it is used in the left-hand-side of the or `||` expression, it evaluates to false and returns the value on the right-hand-side. If, however, one `date` is smaller than the other, it will return a positive or negative number (not necessarily `-1` or `1`).

If you really want to use `-1`, `0` and `1`, then you could do something like:

```js
const dateDiff = new Date(eventOne.date) - new Date(eventTwo.date);
const codeDiff = eventOne.code - eventTwo.code;
return (dateDiff / Math.abs(dateDiff)) || (codeDiff / Math.abs(codeDiff)) || 0;
```

Comment: However dateDiff / Math.abs(dateDiff) gives me NaN

Comment: Ah yes, if `dateDiff` or `codeDiff` is 0, then you get division by zero and therefore `NaN`. Adding a `|| 0` to the end should fix it (will update the answer).